# Selenium Webdriver C# Read Text from ReadOnly Element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I would like a to find a way to store the text from within a read only element.

```
IWebElement LName = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='inputGrid']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]"));
string LNValue = LName.GetAttribute("value");
```

The result of this code is that LNValue is empty.
However, LName is a cell that contains this text: "********"

If I inspect the element, I can see this:

```
<td class="htDimmed fill">********</td>
<td class="htDimmed">*********</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `textContent` attribute to get the text. AFAIK, the `td` element doesnot have a `value` attribute.

```
string LNValue = LName.GetAttribute("textContent");
```

You could also use the `innerText` attribute, but that is not supported across all browsers.

Comment: I used ("textContent"), and this worked!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since code is being written in C#, you can use built in "Text" property to fetch the innerHTML of that element and it should work in all browsers.

```
String LNValue= LName.Text;
```

Moreover make sure that XPath is correctly reaching the element as well..I hope this helps

Comment: Nitpick: In C#, `Text` is a property, not a method. Your example should read: `string LNValue = LName.Text;`

Comment: @JimEvans : thanks for pointing out..updated the answer accordingly :)